# Keras training 1d data vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to create a shallow network that would take a vector and pass it through a network.

I have a vector that is of size 6. vec = [0,1,4,5,1,4,5]

My network:

```
vec_a = Input(shape=(6,))
x_1 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=10, filter_length=1, input_shape=(1, 6), activation='relu')(vec_a)
x_1 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x_1)
```

But I keep getting:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=2

The shape of the training data to the fit function is:
(36400, 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reshape the input data to have the correct input dimension, e.g.:

```
your_input_array.reshape(-1, 6, 1)
```

In addition your input layer should look like:

```
vec_a = Input(shape=(6,1))
```

The reason is that the 1D in Conv1D relates to the use of a sequence. But this sequence can have a vector of multiple values at each position. In your case it is the same, but you have "only" a vector of length 1 in the last dimension.

Comment: But what should be the shape of the data entering the fit function? (36400, 6,1) ?

Comment: Correct, you should also change the dimension of your Input layer (I edited the answer). In addition you can remove the input_shape argument from the following layers, as they are inferred.